# Lyx and Memoir class - setting stock and paper dimensions

Tags: lyx, memoir

I'm using Lyx 2.1.2 and the Memoir class. I want to define a non-standard stock and page size.

Where do I add the commands `\setstocksize`, `\settrimmedsize` and `\settrims`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should go, as part of all layout-related content, in your Document > Settings... > LaTeX Preamble. For example,

[image]

If you want to see the trim lines, add the `showtrims` option to Document > Settings... > Document Class > Class options > Custom.